# Subscribing to a nested Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an app that makes one http request to get a list of items and then makes an http request for each item in the list to get more detailed information about each item.  Effectively:

```
class ItemsService {
  fetchItems() {
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(items => items.map(this.fetchItem(item)));
  }

  fetchItem(item: Item) {
    this.http.get(`${url}/${item.id}`)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Then I'll do something like `itemsService.fetchItems().subscribe(items => console.log(items))` but what ends up happening is I get an array of observables (each response from `fetchItem`). I need to subscribe to each of the internal observables as well so that the `fetchItem` request actually gets triggered.

I've also tried using `flatMap` instead of map but it seems to have the same result in this case. Is there any way for the nested observable to be subscribed to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like the following:

```
function mockRequest() {
    return Observable.of('[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]');
}
function otherMockRequest(id) {
    return Observable.of(`{"id":${id}, "desc": "description ${id}"}`);
}

class ItemsService {
    fetchItems() {
        return mockRequest()
            .map(res => JSON.parse(res))
            .concatAll()
            .mergeMap(item => this.fetchItem(item));
    }

    fetchItem(item: Item) {
        return otherMockRequest(item.id)
            .map(res => JSON.parse(res));
    }
}

let service = new ItemsService();
service.fetchItems().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LPXfqxVsI6Ja2J7RpDYl?p=preview

I'm using a trick with [`.concatAll()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll) to convert an array of Objects such as `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]` into separate values emitted one by one `{"id": 1}`, `{"id": 2}` and `{"id": 3}` (as of now it's an undocumented feature). Then I use [`mergeMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) to fetch their content in a separate request and merge it's result into the operator chain.

This plnkr example prints to console:

```
{ id: 1, desc: 'description 1' }
{ id: 2, desc: 'description 2' }
{ id: 3, desc: 'description 3' }
```

Comment: So in this case `concatAll` is sort of like doing `mergeMap(item => item)`? (or `flatMap`?)

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's the same as `mergeMap(items => Observable.from(items))`

Comment: Why would you need to do `Observable.from(items)`? If items is an array, `flatMap(items => items)` will emit each event when it is subscribed to.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Hmm, I guess you're right, it produces the same result as `concatAll()` although undocumented as well (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/mergeMap.ts#L125 and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L36)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you likely encountered is that you did not flatten *enough*.

`flatMap` or `mergeMap` will flatten `Observables`, `Promises`, `Arrays`, even `generators` (don't quote me on that last one), just about anything you want to throw at it.

So when you do `.flatMap(items => items.map(item => this.fetchItem(item))`, you are really just doing `Observable<Array<Item>> => Observable<Observable<Item>>`

When you just do `map` you are doing `Observable<Array<Item>> => Observable<Array<Observable<Item>>>`.

What you need to do is first flatten out the Array and *then* flatten out each request:

```
class ItemsService {
  fetchItems() {
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    // Implicitly map Array into Observable and flatten it
    .flatMap(items => items)
    // Flatten the response from each item
    .flatMap((item: Item) => this.fetchItem(item));
  }
}
```

Now the above works if you don't mind getting each item response individually. If you need to get all of the items then you should use [`forkJoin`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) on all the inner values, but you would still need `flatMap` in order to flatten the resulting inner value:

```
fetchItems(): Observable<Response[]> {
  return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap(items => {
       const requests = items.map(item => this.fetchItem(item));
       return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(requests);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more why I would need to do `forkJoin`? When subscribing to what is returned by `fetchItems` how would it work different?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it creates a stream which emits a single item, an array of all the last values returned from each of the passed in Observables. Your OP made it sound like you wanted all the responses together as a single value in the output instead of getting each response individually.

Comment: I do, but in this case I can use `.toArray()` right?

Comment: You could yes, the advantage of forkJoin would be that you only need two operators and the order is automatically maintained which is not the same for `.concatMap.mergeMap.toArray`

Comment: Is fewer operators a particular advantage? In this case it doesn't actually reduce the amount of code if you consider `forkJoin` to also be an operator, which I would.

Comment: It usually means fewer object instantiations and fewer subscriptions. It's a small enough difference in this case to come down to semantic preference. It is still preserving order which `.mergeMap.toArray` will not do.

Answer (score -1):

You can break up the items array before the line that calls `this.fetchItem`.
You can use mergeMap on an Observable whose value is an array and each item will be emitted individually.

```
fetchItems() {
    return this.http.get(url)
       .map(res => res.json())
       .mergeMap(arrItem => this.fetchItem(arrItem));
}
```

Edit: I guess I should have provided more explanation. `mergeMap` is synonymous with `flatMap` in rxjs. Typically, you use flatMap when your projection function returns an Observable, but it will also flatten arrays as well, so, calling mergeMap will then emit each item individually, I thought that was what OP wanted to achieve. I also realized, you can combine the `mergeMap` call and last `map` call, because the projection for `mergeMap` will be called for each item in the array, I made the changes in the code above.

Comment: I believe this should be done with mergeMap, but it looks like you've put it in the wrong place. `arrItem` is not an observable, why should it be flattened?

Comment: I don't fully understand what `mergeMap` is doing ... how is this different than using `.flatMap`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It is a synonym. See https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: Does this really work? The response from this call is expected to return an array of objects which is emitted as single value. Then calling `mergeMap()` has no effect because it's called on a single Observable that emits the entire array.

Comment: I don't think this fixes the problem; The observable still gets wrapped. You can subscribe to `mergeMap`, but then observables are emitted and if they are not subscribed to, `fetchItem` is not initiated.