# Merge subarrays using Observables

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have this data structure:

```
[{
    id : 1,
    name : "Item 1",
    subItems : [{
            id : 1,
            name : "SubItem 1"
        },{
            id : 2,
            name : "SubItem 2"
        }
    ]
}, {
    id : 2,
    name : "Item 2",
    subItems : [{
            id : 3,
            name : "SubItem 3"
        }, {
            id : 4,
            name : "SubItem 4"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I make the following call to a web service to get the items:
    `this.dataService.get("items")`

Returned is an `Observable<Item[]>`. What Observable operators can I use to only get a concatenated list of SubItems? I would like to end up with something like this:

```
[{
    id : 1,
    name : "SubItem 1"
}, {
    id : 2,
    name : "SubItem 2"
},
{
    id : 3,
    name : "SubItem 3"
}, {
    id : 4,
    name : "SubItem 4"
}]
```

Should I use something like `flatMap` or `concat`?

Comment: Is the result (the full result) an array? It is not clear from the way you wrote it

Comment: and is it deliberate that you mix subItems and searchProfiles?

Comment: ... and is the source supposed to be an array?

Comment: @Meir It was a type, should be subItems for both of them. The result should be an array, yes.

Comment: Thought so. See my solution below, you can achieve this using the js array functions without a need for further usage rxjs

Comment: @Meir alright! I think this is what I need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided it is a typo and the second element has `subItems` as well (and not `searchProfiles`), you don't need flatMap or any thing of the sort, you can do it in a plain map using js array operators:

```
var transformed = [].concat(...result.map(item => item.subItems));
```

or in your case

```
httpResult$.map(result => [].concat(...result.map(item => item.subItems))
```

if the use of different keys is deliberate, your internal map will require a bit more logic but the mapping will be quite the same

Answer (score 1):

You want to first `map()` operator to extract only fields you need and them flatten the arrays of objects with `concatAll()` (it's a little trick with higher order Observables, see [Subscribing to a nested Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250882/subscribing-to-a-nested-observable/40257871#40257871) for more info):

```
var data = [{
    id : 1,
    name : "Item 1",
    subItems : [
        { id : 1, name : "SubItem 1" },
        { id : 2, name : "SubItem 2" }
    ]
}, {
    id : 2,
    name : "Item 2",
    searchProfiles : [
        { id : 3, name : "SubItem 3" },
        { id : 4, name : "SubItem 4" }
    ]
}];

Observable.from(data)
    .map(item => {
        if (item.searchProfiles) {
            return item.searchProfiles;
        } else if (item.subItems) {
            return item.subItems
        }
    })
    .concatAll()
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This prints to console:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'SubItem 1' }
{ id: 2, name: 'SubItem 2' }
{ id: 3, name: 'SubItem 3' }
{ id: 4, name: 'SubItem 4' }
```

Alternatively, if you really want the output as a single array then you can add `toArray()` operator between `.concatAll()` and `.subscribe(...)` and you'll receive:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'SubItem 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'SubItem 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'SubItem 3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'SubItem 4' } ]
```

Comment: The thing that bugs me is that I in `map` get the entire Array with both items instead of each item, like in your example. In your case, the observable emits each item separately I guess? But I my case, the whole array is returned and emitted once, so that's what I get inside of `map`

Comment: @Joel That's because I'm using `Observable.from(data)`. If you're using `Observable.of(data)` you'll receive it as one large array.

Comment: Ok. And then I would have to do something like `.map(items => { let subItems = []; items.forEach(item => subItems.push(item.subItems)); return subItems;)`? The syntax may be way off though :)

Comment: @Joel Why you need that?

Comment: If using `Observable.of(data)` I need to do something like that to get the result that I want. But thank you, this has helped me.