# Combine multiple observable arrays into new object array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have 3 observable arrays like below.

```
persons = [
   {
      "firstName":"john",
      "lastName":"public",
      "locationID":"1",
      "departmentID":"100"
   },
   {
      "firstName":"sam",
      "lastName":"smith",
      "locationID":"2",
      "departmentID":"101"
   }
]

departments = [{"departmentID": "100",
               "name": "development"
               },
               {"departmentID": "101",
                "name": "sales"
               }]

locations = [{"locationID": "1", "name": "chicago"},
              {"locationID":"2", "name": "ny"}]
```

I am trying to combine these 3 into below result ,

```
result = [
   {
      "firstName":"john",
      "lastName":"public",
      "location":"development",
      "department":"sales"
   },
   {
      "firstName":"sam",
      "lastName":"smith",
      "location":"ny",
      "department":"sales"
   }
]
```

To get the desired result, I have used map function on persons observable to give new object array.

```
this.store<Person>('persons')
.map(function(person){
     let p = new personDetail()
     p.firstName = person.firstName,
     p.lastName = person.lastName
     return p;
})
```

`PersonDetail` object has `firstName`, `lastName`, `location` and `department` properties. How do I do a lookup into departments observable and get a matching row for `departmentID` to get the department name ?

I am new to rxjs library, please let me know if there is a better way to attain the desired result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you'll very likely want to fetch lists of departments and locations from a remote service (make another HTTP request) I'd do it right away with Observables as well.

```
Observable.from(persons)
    .mergeMap(person => {
        let department$ = Observable.from(departments)
            .filter(department => department.departmentID == person.departmentID);

        let location$ = Observable.from(locations)
            .filter(location => location.locationID == person.locationID);

        return Observable.forkJoin(department$, location$, (department, location) => {
            return {
                'firstName': person.firstName,
                'lastName': person.lastName,
                'location': location.name,
                'department': department.name,
            };
        });
    })
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

This prints to console:

```
[ { firstName: 'john',
    lastName: 'public',
    location: 'chicago',
    department: 'development' },
  { firstName: 'sam',
    lastName: 'smith',
    location: 'ny',
    department: 'sales' } ]
```

There're two Observables `department$` and `location$` that are filtered with `filter()` operator to get the only item with matching ID. Then [`forkJoin()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) operator waits until both of them are complete. Operator `mergeMap()` then reemits the value returned from `forkJoin()`. At the end with `toArray()` we collect all items into a single array.

Instead of `Observable.from(...)` you can have whatever service you'll need (eg. `http.get(...)`).

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/nenekup/4/edit?js,console

Similar questions: [Merge subarrays using Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238) and [Subscribing to a nested Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250882/subscribing-to-a-nested-observable/40257871)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working using forkJoin.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on why is needed the mergeMap or what it does?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what exactly your observables are emitting, so I considered two options.

```
let persons = [
    {
        "firstName":"john",
        "lastName":"public",
        "locationID":"1",
        "departmentID":"100"
    },
    {
        "firstName":"sam",
        "lastName":"smith",
        "locationID":"2",
        "departmentID":"101"
    }
];

let departments = [
    {"departmentID": "100", "name": "development"},
    {"departmentID": "101", "name": "sales"}
];

let locations = [
    {"locationID": "1", "name": "chicago"},
    {"locationID": "2", "name": "ny"}
];

// Option 1: first observable emits persons one by one, 
// locations and departments are emitted as whole arrays.
let o1: any = Observable.from(persons);
let o2: any = Observable.of(departments);
let o3: any = Observable.of(locations);

o1.withLatestFrom(o2, o3, (p, d, l) => {
    // here it is probably better to convert array to some kind of map or dictionary,
    // but I'm only showing Rxjs concept of doing such things.
    let location = l.find(c => c.locationID === p.locationID);
    let department = d.find(c => c.departmentID === p.departmentID);
    return {
        firstName: p.firstName,
        lastName: p.lastName,
        location: location ? location.name : "",
        department: department ? department.name : ""
    };
}).subscribe((f) => {
    console.log(f);
});

// Option 2: all observables emit elements one by one.
// In this case we need to convert departments and locations to arrays.
o1 = Observable.from(persons);
o2 = Observable.from(departments);
o3 = Observable.from(locations);

o1.withLatestFrom(o2.toArray(), o3.toArray(), (p, d, l) => {
    // this part of code is exactly the same as in previous case.
    let location = l.find(c => c.locationID === p.locationID);
    let department = d.find(c => c.departmentID === p.departmentID);
    return {
        firstName: p.firstName,
        lastName: p.lastName,
        location: location ? location.name : "",
        department: department ? department.name : ""
    };
}).subscribe((f) => {
    console.log(f);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i think the RxJS .zip operator may be your friend here.

As far as I understand, .zip emits like this ...

```
.zip(
   Observable.from[array1].switchMap( // map to http response here ),
   Observable.from[array2].switchMap( // map to http response here ),
   Observable.from[array3].switchMap( // map to http response here )
).map((valueFromArray1, valueFromArray2, valueFromArray3) {
   // Create your object here 
})
```

Something like that! Hopefully, puts you on the right track.

.zip should emit the first time when all 3 have emitted (and it will emit a second time when all three stream have emitted twice, etc) - In your scenario I expect all three stream emit once only, which makes it a simple case for .zip

Comment: interesting, I didnt know about zip function. I was able to get it working using forkJoin as martin suggested.