# How to flatten Array of Observables in an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to flatten a nested Observable, but I'm not getting it to work:

```
 this.af.object('test/father')
  .map(res => {
    res.namedKeys = [];
    for (let el in res.keys) {
      res.namedKeys.push(this.af.object(`test/keys/${el}`))
    }
    return res
  })
  .flatMap(res => Observable.combineLatest(res))
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log('The final response:', res);
  });
```

I want to get the actual data of the Observables in my Array.
I've tried a lot of different things the last 2 days, but in the end, I receive either nothing or still the Array with Observables in it. The code above is returning nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty hard to see what is the problem  , since you don't supply any structure info.

I *think* you mean :

```
 for (let el in Object.keys(res))
```

instead of

```
 for (let el in res.keys)
```

Also - `combineLatest` expects an observable. you didn't supply one :

Consider using this instead :

```
.flatMap(res => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(Rx.Observable.of(res)))
```

Demo ( which uses rxjs 5 which uses switchmap instead of flatMap)
http://jsbin.com/cuvisecipi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

A better demo which illustrates a similar ( from an array) solution :

http://jsbin.com/punoxitino/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: No, I wanna do something else. When I get the response, I wanna map a property of the response to a new Observable. And in the end I wanna just receive plain data. In The Moment I receive an Observable in my data.

Answer (score 2):

The `.combineLatest` operator would work but it expects an array of Observables. You're passing it an object `res` that contains a property with an array of Observables.

In other words `.combineLatest` needs this: `Observable[]`
But you're passing it: `{ namedKeys: Observable[] }`

So you problem is not simply flattening Observables (like this eg. [Combine multiple observable arrays into new object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255718/combine-multiple-observable-arrays-into-new-object-array/41262155#41262155)) because you need to pass the original objects as well. I'd recommend using `forkJoin` because it collects all items from all source Observables until they complete.

```
this.af.object('test/father')
  .concatMap(res => {
    // the original object is here as well at index 0 
    observables = [ Observable.of(res) ]; 
    for (let el in res.keys) {
      observables.push(this.af.object(`test/keys/${el}`))
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
  })
  .map(([res, ...namedKeys]) => {
    res.namedKeys = namedKeys;
    return res;
  })
  .subscribe(res => { ... });
```