# "Flatten" inner observables

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

How to flatten this array of observables?

```
var observables = [
  Rx.Observable.of(1),
  Rx.Observable.of(2),
  Rx.Observable.of(3)
]

Rx.Observable.of("a").mergeMap(x => {
  return Rx.Observable.from(observables)
}).subscribe(y => {
  console.log(y)
})
```

My expectaction is to get:

```
1
2
3
```

But instead I'm getting

```
ScalarObservable { _isScalar: true, value: 1, scheduler: null }
ScalarObservable { _isScalar: true, value: 2, scheduler: null }
ScalarObservable { _isScalar: true, value: 3, scheduler: null }
```

I searched this site, came across this: [How to flatten Array of Observables in an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652927/how-to-flatten-array-of-observables-in-an-observable) ..., but looks too complicated (?) for what it is. Or probably it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge) them together:

```
Rx.Observable.merge(...observables)
```

```js
const obs$ = [
  Rx.Observable.of(1),
  Rx.Observable.of(2),
  Rx.Observable.of(3),
];

Rx.Observable.merge(...obs$).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but getting the same result. The key difference here, I have to put that Rx.Observable.merge inside another observable.

Comment: @CokordaRaka As my working example shows, this code works perfectly well. If your situation is different from what you described, please edit the question to reflect your actual situation and then I can edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @CokordaRaka You didn't use my answer correctly. Note the `...` spread operator before `observables`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code, containing your suggestion (the merge), I put it inside a concatMap... because thats just the situation Im dealing with, and my need is to produce an array of observables inside that block, and have them merged into the outer observable:

```
observables = [
  Rx.Observable.of(1),
  Rx.Observable.of(2),
  Rx.Observable.of(3)
]

Rx.Observable.of("a").concatMap(x => {
  return Rx.Observable.merge(observables)
}).subscribe(y => console.log(y))
```