# How to map two Oberservable arrays based on a value?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two observable arrays.

```
habits$: Observable<Habit[]>;
status$: Observable<Status[]>;
```

The habit has the following structure:

```
export interface Habit {
  habitId: number;
  name: string;
  repeatVal: number;
  notification: string;
  color: string;
  question: string;
  id: number;
}
```

The status array has the habitId, date and status as keys.

I want to merge both habits$ and status$ into one Observable array based on the habitId attribute present in both of them.

I have done some research and a combination of mergeMap() and forkJoin() seems to be the way to go, like shown here
[Combine multiple observable arrays into new object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255718/combine-multiple-observable-arrays-into-new-object-array)

But I can't figure out a syntax that will work for me.

This is how my code looks at the moment:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.habits$ = this.habitService.fetchAllById(this.authService.userId);
console.log(this.habits$);
this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll();
this.habits$.pipe(
  mergeMap(habits => {
  this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll().filter(status => status.habitId == habits.habitId);
}));
console.log(this.joined$);}
```

Comment: What would be the type of the merged array you are wanting?

Comment: you need to return an observable in your mergemap (I would use switchmap I think), now you are just assigning something: Just do return 
 this.statusService.fetchAll().filter(status => status.habitId == habits.habitId);

Comment: Another Observable array. Basically I want to merge both Observable arrays into one, where the values from the status-Observable get attached to the values of the habit-Observable based on the matching habitId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use forkJoin in the following fashion:

```
ngOnInit() {
  forkJoin([
    this.habitService.fetchAllById(this.authService.userId),
    this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll()
  ]).subscribe(([habits, statuses]) => {
    this.joined = habits.map(habit => ({
      ...statuses.find(t => t.habitId === habit.habitId),
      ...habit 
    }));
  });
}
```

see simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-merge-two-observables-to-single-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the answer, Moshezauros. 

Unfortunately I am getting an error when compiling:   Error: src/app/data-table/data-table.component.ts:68:7 - error TS2740: Type '{ length: number; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; pop(): Habit; push(...items: Habit[]): number; concat(...items: ConcatArray<Habit>[]): Habit[]; concat(...items: (Habit | ConcatArray<...>)[]): Habit[]; ... 28 more ...; status: number; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.

Comment: Could this be because this is returning a subscription and not an observable array?

Comment: How can I make it return an Observable array instead of a subscription?

Comment: you need to specify more code if you want me to help you deubg (stackblitz would be best). `this.joined$` should probably be a BehaviorSubject (and not an observable) and then you write `this.joined$.next(insert_the_new_array_here)`